# GitHub: Merging old branches

Tags: github, branch, branching-and-merging, branching-strategy

So say you branch off your master to create a "new feature #101" for your application.  Now this feature isn't going to be pushed to the master until X months from now (we'll say 3 months).  In that 3 month period, say we branch off other features pushed to the master, and even a few bug fixes directly to master.  We now have a master branch with 14+ commits since our "new feature #101". So now say it's +3 months and time to push "new feature #101", what's the best way to merge that into master?  Do we do a straight merge into the master, do we rebase "new feature #101"?  What's the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge `master` into `new feature #101` first, clean up all merge conflicts, and then it will be a simple merge back into master (also easier to see the diff that way).

Comment: Now would this sill work cleanly when "new feature #101" has a dozen or so commits?

Comment: Yep. The point is that you want your feature branch completely up to date with master, so that the HEAD of your feature branch is just ahead of master, and the merge just switches the pointer of the HEAD.

Comment: So a "newer" master merging into this "new feature" (but has old contents of various files), still clean merge master into new feature?  I think I've got everything figured here correctly.